# How to use Redis cache to cache the Object using spring boot webflux framework having mongodb as datasource

Tags: mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-data-redis-reactive

I tried using `@cachable` annotation and getting error as can't serialize `Mono<Object>` .
It would be helpful if some examples are provided for the mentioned requirement.
also need help with example of how to configure template and connectionfactory and cache manager for reactive framework.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.